# Interperating Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test's p-value

Tags: distributions, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am trying one-sample wilcoxon signed rank test on my data. Data contains 100 values, summary of my data is:

```
> summary(myData)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2370  0.3385  0.3724  0.3585  0.3724  0.4401
```

I want to check if my data is significantly different from a given `number = 0.4400812`. So, I try:

```
wilcox.test(myData, mu=0.4400812)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  myData
V = 28, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0.4400812
```

For me this p-value (`2.2e-16`) is very low, keeping in mind that 7 of the values in `myData` vector are equal to given value (`0.4400812`). Therefore, I do not expect such a low p-value. Can somebody shed some light on this, so that I can understand why is it happening.

dput of myData is:

```
> dput(myData)
c(0.37237643872715, 0.4062288422478, 0.2708192281652, 0.3385240352065, 
0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 
0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.3385240352065, 
0.4062288422478, 0.37237643872715, 0.30467163168585, 0.2708192281652, 
0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 
0.37237643872715, 0.30467163168585, 0.44008124576845, 0.37237643872715, 
0.3385240352065, 0.3385240352065, 0.3385240352065, 0.4062288422478, 
0.3385240352065, 0.30467163168585, 0.4062288422478, 0.4062288422478, 
0.30467163168585, 0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.4062288422478, 
0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.3385240352065, 
0.37237643872715, 0.30467163168585, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 
0.30467163168585, 0.2708192281652, 0.37237643872715, 0.23696682464455, 
0.44008124576845, 0.4062288422478, 0.3385240352065, 0.2708192281652, 
0.44008124576845, 0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 
0.3385240352065, 0.3385240352065, 0.2708192281652, 0.4062288422478, 
0.2708192281652, 0.3385240352065, 0.30467163168585, 0.4062288422478, 
0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.44008124576845, 0.4062288422478, 
0.3385240352065, 0.44008124576845, 0.3385240352065, 0.30467163168585, 
0.23696682464455, 0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 
0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.4062288422478, 
0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.44008124576845, 0.37237643872715, 
0.37237643872715, 0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.44008124576845, 
0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 0.37237643872715, 0.30467163168585, 
0.4062288422478, 0.4062288422478, 0.3385240352065, 0.37237643872715, 
0.4062288422478, 0.3385240352065, 0.4062288422478, 0.4062288422478
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "data is significantly different from 0.44..."?

Comment: **I suspect your data are disguising important clues relating to how they should be analyzed.**  All your values are integers between 7 and 13, multiplied by $50/1477$.  Here is a summary:$$\begin{array}{lrrrrrrr}\text{Value:}&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\\hline\text{Count:}&2&6&9&27&33&16&7\end{array}$$What do these values actually represent?  Are they counts? Raw scores? What is the meaning of the $50/1477$ factor? And where did the threshold of $0.4401$ come from--was that determined from the data or did it arise through independent considerations?

Comment: @MichaelM I want to show that 0.44 is a value which can not be observed by chance. As this value is observed 7 times in a given distribution (vector of 100 values) so the p-value for observing this number in that distribution should be **higher** as compared to a number (let's say 0.50) which has never been observed in the given distribution.

Comment: @whuber I subset a set of observations from an initial population based on some pre-filtering criteria and then I check how many relevant (gold standard) observations are there in the selected observations. This number 0.44 represents the number of gold standard observation preserved by one pre-filtering criteria. Now I want to see if this criteria is better than randomly picking the observations. I make 100 iterations of picking observation randomly and the vector `myData` contains number of gold standard observations picked in every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by addressing the comment asking about how to estimate the probability of getting 0.44008124576845 than the question.

Let's have a look at the data:

```
> table(dades)
dades
0.23696682464455  0.2708192281652 0.30467163168585  0.3385240352065     0.37237643872715 
               2                6                9               27                   33 
 0.4062288422478 0.44008124576845 
              16                7 
> length(dades)
[1] 100
```

That is, the 100 observations of the variable take just seven different values, and just seven observations reach the maximum 0.44008124576845.

If you are interested in the probability of an event, the simplest (and rather well behaved) estimator is the frequency of that event in a sample. Since we have got 7 occurrences of 0.44008124576845 in a 100 observations sample, we can estimate that probability of getting 0.44008124576845 is 7%.

We can go beyond point estimate and get a confidence interval:

```
> prop.test(7,100)

    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  7 out of 100, null probability 0.5
(...)
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03101985 0.14376573
sample estimates:
   p 
0.07
```

That is, with a 95% confidence level, we can say that the probability of getting  0.44008124576845 in your experiment lies between 3.1% and 14.3%.

And as a second part of the answer: does that question in the comment relate to to what is asked in the question?

The question is:

> I want to check if my data is significantly different from a given number = 0.4400812.

I'm afraid there is some confusion on meaning of this question - which is not very clear in itself.

The question the Wilcoxon test you tried can address is "Is the median of this distribution 0.4400812?", and Wilcoxon test just tells that we can be very sure that the median of the distribution is not 0.4400812. If the median was 0.4400812, we could expect to get about the same number of observations over 0.4400812 and under 0.4400812 in our sample, and since 93 out of 100 observations are below it, it is extremely unlikely that the median were 0.4400812 - and that's just what Wilcoxon test says.

Another interpretation of the question -more related to the comment- might be whether the probability of getting 0.4400812 is significantly different from zero. Here the answer is that it is significant. In fact, by showing that you have got at least one observation with that value, you have actually proved that the probability of getting it is different from zero.

Comment: @newbie If you think that the answer answers your question or your concerns, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Though its too late to say but Thank you for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

This test checks if location (think of it as it was median) equals `mu`. And it does not since `mu` is a maximum of you data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you suggest any other test which gives me a p-value w.r.t how much a given number is away from a given distribution.. For example in case I mentioned here I should get a higher p-value as this value has been observed in given data distribution for 7 times. Contrary to this, if I use a greater number in mu (e.g. mu = 2) which has not been observed in given data then I get a significantly low p-value as that number is much bigger then given distribution. I remember your suggestion of using MAD but I need something which gives me a comparative p-value.

Comment: Sorry, nothing else comes to my mind.

Comment: You could estimate the probability of a given number in your distribution, but this is not how usually test work.

Comment: @Pere And how would I estimate it? Can you please elaborate your answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know this too :D